# What does it mean when the badge page says "did not earn this badge"?

Tags: support, badges

Looking at my profile page on Workplace I saw:

[image]

Clicking the badge gives this view:

[image]

Clicking "learn more" then results in this view:

[image]

Huh? What is this saying? Clicking on the badge itself shows I don't have the badge.

Is this another standard "blame caching" issue where the site badge in aggregate isn't updated with the individual badges?

Comment: Yes you should blame caching.  Also, congratulations!

Comment: @Monica not cache in this case, just the delay of the badge awarding script, which isn't instant. OP got the actual badge about two hours after posting this. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The progress tracker on your profile will tell you immediately when you *currently* qualify to be awarded a new badge. However, badge awarding is still not instantaneous. You still have to wait for the relevant script's next run before the system will formally award it to you. Until it does get awarded, you know you don't have to do anything else to qualify for it. The badge is on its way.

The only exception here is tag badges, which *can* be awarded immediately upon viewing your profile when you currently qualify for the badge, under certain conditions.

Comment: +1. I don't recall off-hand how painful it is to check if someone has a given badge, but if it's not too bad, only showing the "congratulations!" bit  when the badge has actually been awarded is probably not a bad idea.

Comment: @AdamLear it'd be a nice UX fix. Not sure who or how many people actually see that page during the interval as it sort of requires earning the _tracked_ badge during a relatively small window of time, but who knows :)